# Selenium to navigate forms and waiting for a file to finish downloading

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I know this question has come up a billion times and that what I want to do isn't Selenium's intended purpose, but I don't know of anything else that can achieve this purpose.  I've read those answers to the best of  my abilities, and lots of documentation, but I could use some pointers.

I'm trying to download a number of files from [CDC Compressed Mortality](http://wonder.cdc.gov/cmf-icd9.html) which requires one to 1) press 'I Agree', 2)  Navigate through a bunch of menus, check boxes and dropdown boxes and 3) press 'Send' and wait for the file to automatically start downloading.

There are a few very troublesome limitations of the webpage which has led me to look for ways to automate this.

- Exporting the resulting dataset using the 'send' button is inconsistent with some settings, omitting data points, namely in some cases the file produced doesn't reflect the settings for suppressed/omitted values
- The page limits the number of lines of data

I've found that by exporting data by individual states, the two points above are no longer a problem however this is super labor intensive, and not much fun.  I should note that I have no experience with Python (or real programming), but the documentation seemed good enough for me to get this to somewhat work. This is what I would like to do:

1. Navigate to page, press 'I accept'
2. Select a State
3. Fill in some options
4. Hit send
5. Wait for file to finish downloading

Since setting the Firefox profile skips the download box, the file automatically begins downloading.  I am able to determine whether a file has finished downloading by finding the newest file and waiting until the *.part* extension is gone.

The code works up until it tries to select **12 Florida**, then, everything just stops.  Firefox freezes and no file ever begins to download.  Repeating this manually, it goes without a problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select, WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import os, unittest, time, re

basedir = os.getcwd()
savedir = os.path.join(basedir, 'download')

# Check download status
def checkdownload():
    os.chdir(savedir)
    files = filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(os.getcwd()))
    files = [os.path.join(os.getcwd(), f) for f in files] # add path to each file
    files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x))
    if not files :
        newest_file = "no"
    else :
        newest_file = files[-1]
    os.chdir(basedir)
    return newest_file



# Set user profile
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir",basedir+'\\download')
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/plain")

# Before anything downloads
previousnew = checkdownload()

# Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
b = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
b.get("http://wonder.cdc.gov/cmf-icd9.html")
b.implicitly_wait(1)

### Find states
b.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/form/div[3]/div/center/input").click() # Press 'I agree'

# print [o.text for o in Select(b.find_element_by_id("SD16.V1")).options]

# Make a list of all the states available
options = Select(b.find_element_by_id("codes-D16.V9")).options
optionsList = []

for option in options: 
    optionsList.append(option.get_attribute("value"))
    if option.get_attribute("value") == "*All*":
        optionsList.remove(option.get_attribute("value")) # Remove the *All* option


# Loop over states individually
for optionValue in optionsList:
    print "\nRunning on %s" % optionValue

    b.get("http://wonder.cdc.gov/cmf-icd9.html")
    b.implicitly_wait(1)

    b.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/form/div[3]/div/center/input").click() # Press 'I agree'

    print "Add Selections"

    # 1. Table layout, id = SB_1 ... SB_5
    Select(b.find_element_by_id("SB_1")).select_by_visible_text("Age Group")
    Select(b.find_element_by_id("SB_2")).select_by_visible_text("Race")
    Select(b.find_element_by_id("SB_3")).select_by_visible_text("Gender")
    Select(b.find_element_by_id("SB_4")).select_by_visible_text("County")
    Select(b.find_element_by_id("SB_5")).select_by_visible_text("Year")

    # 2. Location, id = codes-D16.V9
    Select(b.find_element_by_id("codes-D16.V9")).deselect_by_index(0) # remove *All* option
    Select(b.find_element_by_id("codes-D16.V9")).select_by_value(optionValue) # selection

    # Age Group, id = SD16.V5
    Select(b.find_element_by_id("SD16.V5")).deselect_by_index(0) # remove *All* option
    Select(b.find_element_by_id("SD16.V5")).select_by_value('20-24')
    Select(b.find_element_by_id("SD16.V5")).select_by_value('25-34')
    Select(b.find_element_by_id("SD16.V5")).select_by_value('35-44')
    Select(b.find_element_by_id("SD16.V5")).select_by_value('45-54')
    Select(b.find_element_by_id("SD16.V5")).select_by_value('55-64')

    # Gender, id = SD16.V7
    # Race, id = SD16.V8
    # Hisp, Does not exist in this file

    # Year, id = SD16.V1
    yr = 1997, 1998
    Select(b.find_element_by_id("SD16.V1")).deselect_by_index(0) # remove *All* option
    select = Select(b.find_element_by_id("SD16.V1"))
    for o in yr:
        select.select_by_value("%s" % o)

    # ICD-9 Codes, id = codes-D16.V2
    # Rate per, id = SO_rate_per

    # Other options
    b.find_element_by_id("export-option").click()
    b.find_element_by_id("CO_show_totals").click()
    b.find_element_by_id("CO_show_zeros").click()
    b.find_element_by_id("CO_show_suppressed").click()

    # Submit
    print "Submit"
    b.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/form/table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/div[2]/center/input[1]").click()

    # Check if file has begun downloading
    print "Waiting for new file"
    new = checkdownload()
    while previousnew == new:
        print "... waiting"
        new = checkdownload()
        continue

    print "Waiting for download to finish"
    # New file found, wait until it doesn't have .part extension
    new = checkdownload()
    while os.path.splitext(new)[1] == ".part":
        print "... downloading"
        new = checkdownload()
        continue

    print "Downloaded"

    continue


b.quit()
```

I'm unable to determine why this happens, as no error is produced.  Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

PS. I realize my code is horrendous, and that one honest answer would be 'You're doing everything wrong'.  But, I'm truly at a loss why this simple script is behaving like this.

Comment: Not really an answer, but consider using PhantomJS as your driver. Then eliminate the "controlling Firefox" part of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code. First time, it failed because of `'\\`' as a hardcoded path separator but I'll assume you're on Windows.

Fixed that, second time, it failed due to a race condition that might be your actual problem. Take a look at these lines:

```
os.chdir(savedir)
files = filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(os.getcwd()))
files = [os.path.join(os.getcwd(), f) for f in files] # add path to each file
files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x))
```

You are dealing with files that you know are going to "disappear" (the `.part` files you are checking). If this happens in between `listdir` and `getmtime`, then `getmtime` raises an exception because the file doesn't exist and the script quits without closing Firefox (so it "hangs"). And this is likely because the files are small and download quickly.

When working with operations on files that could fail if the file is deleted, you need to use a `try/catch` block, because whenever you check for existence first, the file could disappear or be renamed immediately after the check. This may require you to use a loop instead of nice list comprehensions and sort, however.

Here is a possible implementation of that function:

```python
def checkdownload():
    max_mtime = 0
    newest_file = ""
    for filename in filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(savedir)):
        path = os.path.join(savedir, filename)
        try:
            mtime = os.path.getmtime(path)
            if mtime > max_mtime:
                newest_file = path
                max_mtime = mtime
        except OSError:
            pass  # File probably just moved/deleted
    return newest_file
```

- `chdir` is neither necessary nor probably a good idea, just refer to the directory you are using.
- Since you are only getting the most recently updated file, sorting the entire list is unnecessary